# byte a=123; byte b=5 byte c= (byte)(a+b); gives -128. Why does this really happen?

Tags: java, binary, decimal, twos-complement

https://www.ideone.com/gYreaO , why does this really happen? Why does it take the two's complement way to display the value?

```
byte a=123;
byte b=5;
byte c=(byte)(a+b);
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: Maximum value for `byte` is 127, so if you add one, it starts at the other side of the spectrum, which is the minimum value of `byte`, which is -128.

Comment: Because the valid range of a `byte` is `-128` to `127`. Not `128`. `System.out.println((byte) 128);`

Comment: When you'll take a look at the answer, think about vote up/accept one ;)

Answer (score 2):

A `byte` which is `8bit` can holds `2^8 = 256` values, first `7b` for value, `1b` for sign, all in the `2-complement` way :

```
-128, -127, ... 0, 1, 2 ..., 126, 127
```

When you are as `127`, and you do `+1`, it goes back the first value of the range because of the bonary operation

```
01111110  126
01111111  127
10000000 -128
10000001 -127
```

[`Code demo`](https://ideone.com/AboDYw)

---

Exactly the same happens, with `int` when you reach `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);                      // -2147483648
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

The byte range is -128 to 127. Here is what happens when you add one to max range of byte:

```
  0 1 1 1  1 1 1 1  -->   127
+ 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1  -->     1
------------------
  1 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  -->  -128
```

Please note that leftmost bit is the sign bit and since the sign bit is set, you can get the value of the variable by two's complement.

Answer (score 1):

The `byte` data type has min value `-128(=-2^7)` and max value `127(=2^7-1)`.  
The addition `(a+b)` produces the result: 
`128` (binary `10000000` for the `int` data type) because it is converted to `int`,  
but the casting `(byte)(a+b)` squeezes it back to 1 byte and you get 
`-128`(binary `10000000` for the `byte` data type).